# Can elements from a System.Collection.Arraylist be compared to see if any of the elements are the same?

Tags: arraylist, vbscript, iteration

Basically what the title of the question asks. If I prompt a user their name, then ask the user to enter any 5 numbers, finally storing the responses into an arraylist.

```
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "What is your name"
name = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter any number"
att1 = CInt(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine)
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter any number"
att2 = Cint(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter any number: "
att3 = CInt(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter any number: "
att4 = CInt(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter any number: "
att5 = CInt(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)

set myNumArray =  CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")

myNumArray.Add att1
myNumArray.Add att2
myNumArray.Add att3
myNumArray.Add att4
myNumArray.Add att5
```

How could I discover if any of the numbers the user returned are the same.

for example, The user enters 5 numbers: 1, 2, 2, 4, 5.  How can i tell if the user entered the 2 twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary (**but** **properly**):

```
Option Explicit

Dim alInp : Set alInp = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
alInp.Add 1
alInp.Add 2
alInp.Add 2
alInp.Add 4
alInp.Add 5

Dim dicInp : Set dicInp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim elm
For Each elm In alInp
    dicInp(elm) = dicInp(elm) + 1
Next
Dim key
For Each key In dicInp
    If dicInp(key) > 1 Then WScript.Echo "found", key, dicInp(key), "times"
Next
```

ouput:

```
cscript 34890229.vbs
found 2 2 times
```

**Or** - look at the current content of the ArrayList by using it `.Contains` method:

```
Option Explicit

Dim alInp : Set alInp = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim elm
For Each elm In Array(1, 2, 2, 4, 5)
    If alInp.Contains(elm) Then
       WScript.Echo "not again:", elm
    Else
       alInp.Add elm
    End If
Next
WScript.Echo Join(alInp.ToArray())
```

output:

```
cscript 34890229-2.vbs
not again: 2
1 2 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        On Error Resume Next
        Line=Inp.readline
        Dict.Add Line, ""
        If Err.Number <> 0 then
            If LCase(Arg(1)) = "l" then
                Dict.Remove Line
                Dict.Add Line, ""
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    For Each thing in Dict.Keys()
        Outp.writeline thing
    Next
```

**DeDup**

```
filter dedup {f|l}
filter dup {f|l}
```

Removes duplicate lines in a file keeping either the first or last occurence

```
f - keeps the first occuring duplicate line
c - keeps the last occuring duplicate line
```

**Example**

```
filter dedup f < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

Filter reads and writes standard in and standard out only. These are only available in a command prompt.

```
filter <inputfile >outputfile
filter <inputfile | other_command
other_command | filter >outputfile
other_command | filter | other_command
```